# Integrate external app using IFrame (not Canvas) and Security review

Tags: managed-package, security-review, isv, canvas, iframe

I have a customer that wants to **integrate an external Java App** with a Managed Package. As the endpoint (domain name) of the external Java App(s) is not static but differs from customer to customer we cannot use the Salesforce-preferred **Canvas** solution.

The IFrames just will render some parts of the UI of the external App. Besides, the external App will use Standard Salesforce APIs to modify Salesforce data in a compliant way.

The question now is can we just use regular `iframe` embedded into Lightning Components that send a few uncritical Ids as GET parameters?

- Is this still technically feasible?
- And will this pass Security Review?
- What about cross-domain issues that always come up with `iframe`? Is there a way to circumvent them? Using `apex:iframe`?

Comment: Totally missed that in the question. Hopefully someone will have an answer, but I don't have the experience to answer it authoritatively. Your best bet would still be to talk to the SR team rather than depend on the community.

Comment: It'd be good if you come back and post your experiences once you're through this, too :)

Comment: We didn’t use iFrame at all and made a proper integration using a REST api and LWC User Interface.